# stuck at theme menu fix

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress plugin and one such plugin was somehow active which updated the theme navigation system and i am stuck now, tying hard to fix it

here is the website link:

[thewebsite](https://www.bodafide.ca/)

i am using the theme for the above website

> https://demo.themesuite.com/automotive-wp/

please guide me how and what i can do to make a quick fix temporarily so i can somehow make it work and later when i have time, i can check with backups and all.

I am seriously stuck and compared all versions of files and everything good, i had even restored the previous version of the theme but still it is an issue.

Comment: You are getting about 50+ errors in your console(hit F12 and click console) I surgest you fix them first.

Comment: i can't see them, when i load website, it does not show me

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - I'm not seeing the errors either, when I pull up the site (with and without uBlock) I don't see any errors or warnings in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme/website updated and it's attempting to use `display: flex` on a few items, which you don't have appropriately configured to take advantage of that yet.

To "roll it back" as it were, you can temporarily set the affected items back to `display: block;`

```
.navbar, #menu-main-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Also, I'd suggest taking automatically scheduled backups of your site so you can rollback updates that break it, either at the server level or using one of the many Backup plugins available (BackDraft, BackupBuddy, Snapshot, BackWPUp, etc.)

Also, if you ever need a reference to how your site looked prior to an update, consider using http://web.archive.org's Wayback Machine.

Here's how I could compare the site to what it looked like: http://web.archive.org/web/20171001101613/https://www.bodafide.ca/